# How do I create a .xession / .xinitrc file to launch the default Xubuntu-Session?

Tags: gdm, login-screen, xubuntu, slim

I'm trying to use SLiM instead of GDM as a login manager, but I fail miserably when creating the proper .xsession / .xinitrc file needed by SLiM.

How would a proper .xession file look like to start the Xubuntu-Session? There are great guides about setting up custom Desktop Environments, but I am missing something.

I tried copying contents of the xubuntu.desktop files in `/usr/share/xsessions/` which reads "`Exec=/usr/share/xubuntu/session.sh`" into a .xsession file, but SliM would not show up. What else could I be missing?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in your `slim.conf`

`login_cmd exec ck-launch-session /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session`

or in your .xinitrc

`exec ck-launch-session /usr/share/xubuntu/session.sh`

reference: [debian](http://wiki.debian.org/Xfce) [arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Slim)

Comment: It worked - partially! On boot, xorg went into save graphics mode warning, without working recovery options tho. However, logging in on tty1 I could do sudo slim with a working session!

Comment: What is ck-launch-session?

Comment: AFAIK its a command provided by console-kit to manage session based on user settings.